# How to refer to people from a region?

Tags: grammar

Are below expressions correct to refer to people from the same region?

The Asians people

The Cameroonians people

The Canadians people

The Colombians people

The Chadians people

The Croatians people

The Ecoadorians people

The Egyptians people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from the fact that a word like *Japanese* or *Peruvian* can be used as an adjective or a noun.

We can say "the Canadian people" to refer to Canadians collectively, but we do not say "the Canadians people". When used as an adjective, we do not add an -s:

> ***Peruvian people; Jamaican coffee; Corinthian leather*** (**NOT** "the Peruvians* people")

However, we can use the plural form if we don't say the word *people*:

> Maulik is an Indian; Colleen and Julian are **Americans**.

So, we can say:

- The Serbians

or:

- The Serbian people

but not:

- The Serbians people

Moreover there are some cases where the -s is not added, even to the noun. These are okay as plural nouns:

- The Japanese
- The Japanese people
- The French
- The French people

but **not**:

- The Japaneses*, The Frenches*

even though you could say:

- The Australians, the Turks

---

<sup>*An asterisk indicates an incorrect word</sup>

Comment: In *the Japanese*, *Japanese* is still an adjective, functioning as a fused-modifier head. For more info see [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44655084#44655084).

Comment: @userr2684291 - Yes, that’s a good point; it can indeed function that way. It can function as a noun, as in: _The Japanese are in favor of the accord_, or as an adjective in a noun phrase, as in: _The Japanese contingent expressed their approval of the accord_.

Comment: It's a bit misleading to talk about words functioning as certain lexical categories. Lexical categories aren't functions. A modifier is a function, and so is a subject, and so is a head, or a dependent. The authors of CGEL (2002) tried to give the most parsimonious analysis of certain phenomena. That's why they avoid analyzing *Japanese* in *The Japanese are in favor...* as a noun (there's no need to assign it to a different lexical category when everything can be explained with them remaining adjectives).

Answer (score -2):

As a general rule it is usually considered politically incorrect to call groups of people The _______ people. If you are going to use this phrase anyway, it is bad grammar to put an 's' on the end of the name. So you should say'The Asian people' instead of 'The Asians people'.

Phrases such as 'The ________ people' can be used, but care should be taken to ensure that they are used respectfully and do not cause offence.

To complete your list:

> People from Asia are called Asian, as a group they can be called Asians.
>
> People from Cameroon are called Cameroonian, as a group they can be called Cameroonians.
>
> People from Canada are called Canadian, as a group they can be called Canadians.
>
> People from Colombia are called Colombian, as a group they can be called Colombians.
>
> People from Chad are called Chadian, as a group they can be called Chadians.
>
> People from Croatia are called Croatian, as a group they can be called Croatians.
>
> People from Ecuador are called Ecuadorian, as a group they can be called Ecuadorians.
>
> People from Egypt are called Egyptian, as a group they can be called Egyptians.

You cannot always just add 'ian' to the end of a country's name to determine the name given to its inhabitants. e.g.

> People from Japan are called Japanese, as a group they are still called Japanese.
>
> People from England are called English, as a group they are still called English.
>
> People from France are called French , as a group they are still called French.

The attached link will take you to a site that gives you the names of people from most countries in the world. [Names of People from Different Countries](https://researchmaniacs.com/Demonyms/WhatArePeopleFromDifferentCountriesCalled.html)

Obviously, the names above, and the names contained in the link, are the names used by English speakers. Those names will almost certainly not be applicable in other countries, including the countries in the link.

Comment: One could also add an -s, because the word _people_ is plural: _People from Egypt are called Egyptians; people from Canada are called Canadians_. Moreover, it's worth noting that **many** instances of "the ______ people" are not "politically incorrect;" in the right context, this expression can be used respectfully. Some excerpts from recent news stories include a boxer's quote: _"For this fight, I must be in the best possible shape to provide a great victory for the Croatian people,"_ and a poll report: _The majority of the French people are in favour of raising the price of alcohol_.

Comment: @J.R.  I was referring to the 's' in the OP's original list. You can certainly call people from Croatia Croatians, but you cannot call them The Croatians people. The plural in this case is incorrect. Also, I did not say that **all** instances of the ______ people" are "politically incorrect. I specifically said that "As a general rule it is usually considered politically incorrect". I agree that there are times when it is acceptable, but that does not mean that we should not think twice before doing so.

Comment: I know what you were referring to, and I caught the "general rule" part of your answer. Nevertheless, were I a learner reading this answer (as it is written right now), I might very well (1) assume or deduce that I should **avoid** saying "The _____ people," because it's "usually considered polittically incorrect," and (2) wonder if words like _Chadians_ or _Cameroonians_ are incorrect, because your answer doesn't make mention of them, and you specifically say "it's bad grammar" to do so.

Comment: But according to below link, The ... people shouldn't be incorrect.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/people-and-places/nationalities-languages-countries-and-regions

Comment: @J.R. My apologies, the tag "The Asians people' atop my quote box was a remnant left over from a cut and paste. I thought that I had removed it previously, so I was surprised to see it still there.  Thank you for letting me know that it was still there. I have now removed it.  I have amended my answer to take some of your feedback into account. I did not say that it is bad grammar to add an 's' to the end of a name, I said that it is bad grammar to add an 's' if you are using the phrase "The _____ people", and I included a correct example of its use using the word 'Asian".

Comment: You have still missed "The"